# SQL Server 2008 Proc fails in 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Lending].[uspHMDALarIncomeGet] (@ApplicationId int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    -- Total Income Data
    DECLARE @ApplicantId int = (SELECT AT.ApplicantId FROM Lending.Applicant AT WHERE AT.ApplicationId = @ApplicationId)

    SELECT
    I.Amount
    FROM Lending.Income I WHERE I.ApplicantId = @ApplicantId

END
```

Do you guys know how this proc can be written to succeed in 05?

-Scott

Comment: Can you tell us what error you're getting, and what this line is for: DECLARE @ApplicantId int = (SELECT AT.ApplicantId FROM Lending.Applicant AT WHERE AT.ApplicationId = @ApplicationId)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL2005 does not have the syntax to declare and assign a variable in the same statement. You would need to change

```
  DECLARE @ApplicantId int = (SELECT ...
```

To

```
  DECLARE @ApplicantId int

  SELECT  @ApplicantId = AT.ApplicantId 
  FROM Lending.Applicant AT 
  WHERE AT.ApplicationId =   @ApplicationId
```

**Edit:**

It's just occurred to me that I might have changed the semantics a bit there if there can ever be more than one row matching `AT.ApplicationId =   @ApplicationId`.

```
DECLARE @ApplicantId int

SET  @ApplicantId = (SELECT AT.ApplicantId ...
```

Would retain the original semantics and cause an error in that event.

Comment: I knew it had to be something small! Thanks so much your a lifesaver.